# Unmanned aerial vehicles communication link: frequency/spectrum?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, frequency

I am studying airborne platform:

1. HAP - high altitude platform
2. LAP- low altitude platform
3. UAV - unmanned aerial vehicle

ITU gives frequency allocation bands for link between ground and HAP/LAP/UAV, but there is no information what the frequency is used in the link between them: HAP to HAP link, LAP to LAP link, UAV to UAV link.

I have heard that it is possible to use the same frequency as it was allocated for the inter-satellite link, but I am unsure if it is correct.

Recently I have found a paper "[On the impact of inter-UAV communications
interference in the 2.4 GHz band](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7986413)" ( sorry didn't find it in open access). we study the performance of communication links between drones in the 2.4 GHz wireless band. It is WiFi 2.4 GHz band.

Does anyone know any regulatory documents for inter-platform links?

Comment: What about UAV-LAP links, and manned aircraft-UAV|LAP|HAP communication? Is that inside the scope of your question as well?

Comment: @DeltaLima, yes, it is. Honestly, I am confused about LAP and UAV. In one literature, UAV is LAP platform. So I have decided to assume LAP and UAV as two different platforms

Comment: UAV is a generic term for any unmanned flying thingy. LAP and HAP are both platforms: this term is typically used for a vehicle that is carrying either sensors (typically earth observation, but could also be atmospheric measurements) or communication infrastructure (networking). When we are talking about using a UAV for transportation of goods, the terms HAP or LAP are not used.

Comment: for inter UAV communication, there are several use-cases, and each may use a different link frequency. For example, inter aircraft communication for traffic management (traffic separation/detect & avoid, collision avoidance) will likely use a different frequency than payload data communication. Yet another frequency may be used for command and control purposes. Are you looking for any use-case specifically?

Comment: @DeltaLima. I did not consider any use cases yet. Currently, I would like to define frequency allocation for inter-platform links or satellite-platform link. I have read it is considered an optical link between HAP and satellite ( LEO or GEO) and HAP-HAP link, but optical between drones, I am unsure if it is possible.

Comment: @DeltaLima Is there a document with frequency allocation/spectrum for inter-platform communication? I read it will be under discussion in WRC2023. ok, but we have already had a lot of UAV devices in the air communicating with each other. They have already used a spectrum.

Comment: @DeltaLima As I know, please correct me if I am wrong, drones use today's wifi for communication with each other.  In one another forum, an user suggest me to use any frequency allocated for inter-satellite link except aeronautical frequencies.

Comment: @DeltaLima where can I find the spectrum for use cases you mentioned in one of the your comments (traffic management and payload data communication)?